# how to convert a flat javascript array into a nested graph structure?

Tags: javascript, json, object, translate

how would I convert this flat json structure:

```
[
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["a","b","d"],
    ["c","b","e"],
    ["c","b","f"]
]
```

Into the following graph structure using javascript?

```
{"uri": "a", "subItems": [
    {"uri": "b", "subItems": [
        {"uri": "c", "subItems": [
            {"uri": "b", "subItems": [
                {"uri": "e"},
                {"uri": "f"}
            ]}
        ]},
        {"uri": "d"}
    ]}
]}
```

Comment: Could you explain the structure you want returned? The example isn't quite doing it for me.

Comment: Is your data guaranteed not to have circular references? What have you got so far?

Comment: So if the `"c"` name already exists anywhere in the structure, use it; otherwise create a new top-level name?

Comment: It won't have circular references and there would only be one top node. I'm essentially serializing structured data into flat data, and need to be able to format it back to the structured data somehow on the client. Haven't gotten too far with this :(

Comment: Is there any reason you can't serialize it to JSON? It'll make your life a lot easier...

Comment: I'm using a triplestore which outputs the data flat (although it exists in the triplestore as a graph - or series of graphs) - all of this is JSON, it's just not structured in the output. I feel like I have to recursively search the flat data for the top level item (a) and then find all relationships to a, then all relationships to it's relationships, over and over again until there is nothing left - maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: At the moment your example has a circular reference from what I can tell, b->c->b->c

Comment: @david It's a "different B" (one that is a child of A, and one that is a child of C ... yeah, confusing.) Otherwise it could be expressed as just a sequence of parent-child.

Comment: how do you know that the 'c' at the end of a,b,c is not different from the 'c' in c,b,e and c,b,f?

Comment: Because that's not how it's drawn ;-) It looks like a flat tree lookup based on first field only. Then middle field is always a child of that and last is always a child of the middle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a flat javascript data structure into a graph structure with nested sub children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297281/how-do-i-convert-a-flat-javascript-data-structure-into-a-graph-structure-with-nes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should get you REALLY close. It wraps the entire JSON result in an array, which was done to simplify the getNode function but you could easily just grab the [0] index of the array. I started out trying to conform to JSLint (hence the i = i + 1 instead of i++), but I gave up half way through so the code could be cleaned up a bit. ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/Zcyca/

```
var i, j, k, arr = 
[
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["a","b","d"],
    ["c","b","e"],
    ["c","b","f"]        
];

var results = [];
var last = results;

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 1) {
    var subArr = arr[i];  
    var parentURI = subArr[0], middleURI = subArr[1], childURI = subArr[2]; 
    var parent, middle, child;

    // Find parent or create parent
    parent = getNode(results, parentURI);        
    if(parent === null) {
        results.push({"uri": parentURI, "subItems": []});
        parent = results[results.length-1];
    }        
    if(typeof parent["subItems"] === "undefined") {
        parent["subItems"] = [];
    }

    // Find middle or create middle
    middle = getNode(parent["subItems"], middleURI);
    if(middle === null) {
        parent["subItems"].push({"uri": middleURI, "subItems": []});
        middle = parent["subItems"][parent["subItems"].length-1];        
    }
    if(typeof middle["subItems"] === "undefined") {
        middle["subItems"] = [];
    }    

    // Find child or create child 
    child = getNode(middle["subItems"], childURI);
    if(child === null) {
        middle["subItems"].push({"uri": childURI});
        //child = middle["subItems"][middle["subItems"].length-1];            
    }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(results));

function getNode(arr, uri) {
    var node = null;

    (function recurseArr(arr) {
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 1) {
            var obj = arr[i];
            if(obj["uri"] === uri) {
                node = arr[i];
                break;   
            } else if(typeof obj["subItems"] !== "undefined") {  
                recurseArr(obj["subItems"]);
            }
        }
    })(arr);      

  return node;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not "easy" way it seems.

I wasn't sure how to handle what to do where t needs to find another match for example if you were to add `["b", "e", "b"]` where should it go? the "b" on the second level or the fourth?

http://jsfiddle.net/qVFCe/3/

```
var data = [
["a", "b", "c"],
["a", "b", "d"],
["c", "b", "e"],
["c", "b", "f"]
];

var group = null;

var baseStructure = {
    "uri": null,
    "subItems": []
};


function find(parent, uri) {
    for (var i = 0; parent.subItems && i < parent.subItems.length; i++) {
        if (parent.subItems[i].uri == uri) {
            return parent.subItems[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function findRecursive(parent, uri) {
    var i, obj;
    //look in children
    for (i = 0; parent.subItems && i < parent.subItems.length; i++) {
        obj = find(parent.subItems[i], uri);
        if (obj !== null) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    //look recursively in children
    for (i = 0; parent.subItems && i < parent.subItems.length; i++) {
        obj = findRecursive(parent.subItems[i], uri);
        if (obj !== null) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


for (var i = 0; (group = data[i]); i++) {
    var current = baseStructure;
    for (var j = 0; j < group.length; j++) {
        var obj = find(current, group[j]);

        if (obj === null && j === 0) {
            obj = findRecursive(current, group[j]);
        }

        if (obj === null) {
            //create a new one if not found
            obj = {
                uri: group[j]
            };
            if(current.subItems === undefined)
            {
                current.subItems = [];
            }
            current.subItems.push(obj);
        }
        current = obj;
    }
}
```